# How to comprehend that "lua_Hook is called when it jumps back in the code(This event only happens while Lua is executing a Lua function.)"?

Tags: lua

As per the documentation(https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_sethook), which says[empasise mine]:

> Argument f is the hook function. mask specifies on which events the
> hook will be called: it is formed by a bitwise OR of the constants
> LUA_MASKCALL, LUA_MASKRET, LUA_MASKLINE, and LUA_MASKCOUNT. The count
> argument is only meaningful when the mask includes LUA_MASKCOUNT. For
> each event, the hook is called as explained below:
>
> The call hook: is called when the interpreter calls a function. The
> hook is called just after Lua enters the new function, before the
> function gets its arguments.
>
> The return hook: is called when the
> interpreter returns from a function. The hook is called just before
> Lua leaves the function. There is no standard way to access the values
> to be returned by the function.
>
> The line hook: is called when the
> interpreter is about to start the execution of a new line of code, or
> ***when it jumps back in the code*** (even to the same line). (***This event
> only happens while Lua is executing a Lua function.***)

How to comprehend that `lua_Hook` is called when it jumps back in the code(This event only happens while Lua is executing a Lua function?

Comment: Probably this means that a C function (invoked from Lua code, e.g. `math.sin`) has returned and the Lua code continues to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can look at the source (Lua 5.4):

```
int luaG_traceexec (lua_State *L, const Instruction *pc) {
  -- some parts removed
  if (mask & LUA_MASKLINE) {
    if (npci == 0 ||  /* call linehook when enter a new function, */
        pc <= L->oldpc ||  /* when jump back (loop), or when */
        changedline(p, pcRel(L->oldpc, p), npci)) {  /* enter new line */
      int newline = luaG_getfuncline(p, npci);
      luaD_hook(L, LUA_HOOKLINE, newline, 0, 0);  /* call line hook */
    }
  }
  return 1;  /* keep 'trap' on */
}
```

As can be seen, `LUA_HOOKLINE` is called in three cases: (1) enter a new function, (2) jump back (loop), or (3) enter new line.

"Enter new line" is checked by a call to `changedline`:

```
static int changedline (const Proto *p, int oldpc, int newpc) {
  while (oldpc++ < newpc) {
    if (p->lineinfo[oldpc] != 0)
      return (luaG_getfuncline(p, oldpc - 1) != luaG_getfuncline(p, newpc));
  }
  return 0;  /* no line changes in the way */
}
```

This returns true if the new instruction is on a different line from the previous instruction.

`luaG_getfuncline` gets the line number for the instruction if there is debug information available. The function being checked is the active lua function based on the the current call info value.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. How to comprehend that lua_Hook is called when it jumps back in the code( I think it has some relation with `pc <= L->oldpc`, which is emphasized by you)? But I know I don't fully understand it.

Comment: `pc` (program counter) points to the next instruction to be executed. If it's less/equal than the previous/current instruction, so it's a jump back, which happens with loops on the same line, for example, `for i = 1, 3 do print(i) end` will get 3 line hook calls.

Comment: I see. My understanding of this question is at a different level with your help. I have tried to run a code snippet (like the one aforementioned), but I don't fully understand it before you explain it to me.